# A modification in an environment

Tags: equations, align, line-breaking

I wanna type some lengthy formulae. It's clear that using `align` would be a good option. When latex complies with a lengthy formula, it puts all of the equations on a page. Since there are some texts there, I'd like to break them into two pages conserving their alignment. This goal is easily done by

```
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}
All equations....
\end{align}
\endgroup
```

If I define a new environment such as

```
\newenvironment{myalign}{
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}}{
\end{align}
\endgroup}
```

it would not be complied and I get error. How can I modify the `align` environment to include breaking equations option using above commands?

Comment: you don't need the begingroup and endgroup (an environment is a group) and can use `\align` and `\endalign` but why do this locally? it is normally a document level choice whether to allow breaks, so just need `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do the same as the OP. These are for last minute adjustments for manuscripts where the only solution is so break an align. We generally never allow `\allowdisplaybreaks` globally as it requires a lot of hassle with ``\\*`` etc.

Comment: I would suggest a wrapper env instead, I usually use `\begin{AllowDisplayBreaks}...\end{...}` which then adds `\allowdisplaybreaks` locally. Then one does not have to mess with envs that might not like being inside env definitions.

Comment: In my opinion, the best strategy is to typeset the document without `\allowdisplaybreaks` and, at the end, to add `\displaybreak` at the appropriate spots. This is because `\allowdisplaybreaks` doesn't let you choose where the break happens.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you so much. I did not care about the point you mentioned. You're right.